# Wave interference like render effect

Tags: rendering, graphics

(Someone on gaming told me to better post this here.)

So in a lot of games lately I've seen this weird "light interference effect" where objects on the edges of my screen become red and blue blurry. My questions are:

- What's this effect's name?
- Why is it there?
- Why do so many games use
  it?

Here's a picture of what I mean: [image: https://i.imgur.com/goEW4Vn.png]

Comment: Presuming it is intentional (and not a bug) it looks a little like [chromatic abberation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration), and we [have a question about how to implement that](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58408/how-would-you-implement-chromatic-aberration) here.

Comment: *"Why is it there?"* *"Why do so many games use it?"* Because it looks fancy I guess. :P